# Error installing cx_Freeze on Ubuntu 16.04 [Errno 2]

Tags: python, installation, cx-freeze, setup.py, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install cx_Freeze on Ubuntu 16.04. Pip installation does not work, so I have downloaded a tarball (tar.gz), extracted it and moved the cx_Freeze folder to my home directory.

I have navigated to the cx_freeze folder and used this command:

```
sudo python setup.py build
```

and this went through without any errors, but when I try to install it with:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

I end up with this error:

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'samples'
```

I read somewhere about absolute path etc., but I am unsure how I am supposed to tell cx_Freeze's setup script the absolute path it is working, or if this has much to say.

Hopefully someone can help me with this issue.

Kind regards.

Edit: I am on a 64-bit version of Ubuntu

Comment: You could try to install newer version of cx_Freeze, `pip install --user https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/get/tip.tar.bz2` (or `sudo pip install https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/get/tip.tar.bz2`)

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J.J. Hakala's suggestion to install the newest version of cx_freeze with pip, as well as him providing the correct link to the source, made it possible for me to install cx_freeze with the code he posted in his comment:

```
sudo pip install https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/get/tip.tar.bz2
```

I'm posting the solution as an answer here since he left a comment, but if he wants to post the solution as an answer himself, I'll mark that answer as the one that solved the problem.